# Are women allowed to write a commentary on a book of Tanakh in Orthodox Judaism?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, women, chinuch-education

Miryam was a prophetess, and Deborah was a judge.  Are women allowed to teach men or to write a commentary on a book of Tanakh according to halakhah?

Comment: As an example of a modern sefer, consider [Eishes Chayil by Shira Hochheimer](http://www.feldheim.com/eishes-chayil.html) which has haskomos by Rabbi Zev Leff and Rabbi Ahron Lopiansky. Given that they have provided haskomos, it would appear to be allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Women are indeed able to teach and write commentaries on Tanakh. There are many such examples. One of the most famous is [Nechama Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nechama_Leibowitz) who taught Torah for more than 55 years and was awarded the Israel Prize in education. Her writings on the weekly Torah portion were read by thousands as published and an edited selection were later published as [books](http://a.co/bC22Stv).

A more recent example is Sivan Rahav-Meir whose writings on the weekly Torah portion are followed by [260,000+](https://www.facebook.com/SivanRahavNews/) people on facebook (English [here](https://www.facebook.com/Sivan-Rahav-Meir-262167194201598/)) and who recently published a first [book](http://a.co/9xuwVJx) on the topic.

Finally, Koren is publishing a number of prominent women as part of their [Maggid studies in Tanakh](https://korenpub.com/collections/maggid-studies-in-tanakh).

Comment: @patient R. Mazuz and R. Ovadya Yosef seem fine with her writings: https://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/12941.

Comment: Yes, there are so many well-known women who teach Torah to the masses, and publish numerous sefarim, even if they are not straight "commentaries on Tanach". Yehudis Samet, Yemimah Mizrachi, Esther Yungreis... They often say wonderful insights and are very worth reading, and more power to them.

Comment: @MichoelR some hold that Orchot Tzaddikim was written by a woman