# Sefer written by a woman?

Tags: jewish-books

I remember hearing once about a sefer written by a woman that people were learning but then it was banned.  Do you the name of the sefer/author?

*I think it was written in pre-war Europe

Comment: Pachad Yitzchok?:) just kidding.

Comment: Megillas Esther?

Comment: related: [Are women allowed to write a commentary on a book of Tanakh in Orthodox Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87389/11501)

Comment: Are you referring to sefarim on the parsha by Nechama Leibowitz?

Comment: @Tesvov no, I believe it was a sefer with the author's own commentary and insights.  Are Nechama Leibowitz's sefarim banned?

Comment: I heard that Ikar Sifsei Chachomim was written by a woman, but it is widely learned

Comment: @user6591 I don't get it

Comment: @dreamer No I have never heard so

Comment: And [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dreamer and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @ezra there have been long (un)substantiated rumors that Rav Hutner's famous work was not written by him, but rather his daughter Reb Berurya David wrote it based on his shiurim/notes.

Comment: I don't know about one written in the period you mention, but here is a modern one: https://www.thecjm.org/exhibitions/60

Comment: @user6591, I'm pretty sure that she was the editor, if nothing else

Comment: @Noach I put the 'un' in parenthesis so everyone can continue believing whatever we want. It was an equal opportunity comment:)

Comment: why was it banned?

Comment: Orchos Tzadiqim is anonymous, only quotes sources from Tanach or common-knowledgy Chazals. Whenever the oldest known edition is in Yiddish, they trot out the theory that it's an anonymous work because the author realized it wouldn't be learned if people knew she was a woman. Given topic, source choices, and language and combined evidence. Right now, though, Hebrew is winning the antiquity race. But I wouldn't be sure the topic is closed forever. Never was banned, but this comment chain left that in the dust a long time ago.

Comment: https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/26225-yoatzot-and-she-elot

Answer (score -1):

I have heard it alleged that The Kol Bo (1490) was written by a woman.
The Hornstiplers daughter supposedly wrote on hilchos shabus.
And Reb Buriah David may have written her fathers Pachad Yitzchok

Comment: The list of literary output by women is longer but do you have knowledge (sources) of any of them being banned? (IOW, this doesn’t answer OP’s question.)

Comment: any sources other than your word? Forget about being banned or not, just souces

Comment: I've heard that the Migdal Oz - a commentary on the Rambam often omitted by students, although printed in most Rambams, was written by a woman. I have never found a source, although i tried looking...

Comment: There's a Book that could be helpful... The literary imagination Ultra Orthodox Jewish women by Alyse Fisher Roller

Comment: @chortkov2 it was written by R. Shem Tov ibn Gaon, who was decidedly not a woman